# How to set content-disposition to inline for static file(s) in java Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, content-disposition, static-files

I know how to set content-disposition header for dynamic requests, but how to set it for static files.

Problem is that GAE java production version automatically sets to **attachment** content-disposition for static file requests (btw default local development content-disposition is inline), but I need to set it to **inline**.

Now when somebody tries to open static pdf file browser automatically starts download instead to try to open it in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my pdf files are under /pdf/ path. I have created web request for /pdfi/ uri that with url fetch service fetches requested file under /pdf/ path and sets content-disposition to inline.

Now where ever (static html, etc.) there was link for any pdf file I have replaced /pdf/ with /pdfi/ and everything works. When and if GAE team allow us to set content-disposition for static files I will simply change every link from /pdfi/ to /pdf/

Answer (score 1):

Besides mime type and expiration, you don't have much control over how static files are served (see Google [app.yaml documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_Directory_Handlers)).  If you need fine-grained control, you can store the PDF in the Datastore as a [Blob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Blob) and write a handler for it.

(Not to be confused with the [Blobstore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/))

Comment: I know about Blob because we use it for app created pdfs and there we can set content-disposition to inline. Solution with Blob storage for static files is a little bit inconvenient.